# I'm trying to make Land cover map in GEE with training data and test data but my code is not working. Help me correct my code

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

```
// Acquire satellite imagery
var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterBounds(AOI)
  .filterDate('2023-01-01', '2023-05-16')
  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 5)
  .median();
  Map.centerObject(AOI, 10);

// Clip to kanglung
var Kanglung = image.clipToCollection(AOI);

// Display  sentinal-2 image
Map.addLayer(Kanglung, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 3000}, 'Basemap');

// Create a FeatureCollection for training points
var trainingPoints = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.49607249720904,27.272079167654912), {'landcover': '0'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.49006434901568,27.274901854533898), {'landcover': '0'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.5687753791699,27.264982334643857), {'landcover': '0'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.53187606135342,27.294926722281268), {'landcover': '0'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.56423529436304,27.277132703578683), {'landcover': '0'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.55831297685816,27.26996155678885), {'landcover': '0'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.52003248979761,27.269770828482958), {'landcover': '1'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.51213606645777,27.25794503441248), {'landcover': '1'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.51419600298121,27.256800535977945), {'landcover': '1'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.51018341829493,27.256380883600883), {'landcover': '1'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.52266187676341,27.285781621144103), {'landcover': '1'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.52459306725413,27.287269078897424), {'landcover': '1'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.52626676567942,27.28505695502261), {'landcover': '1'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.50412244805247,27.285991392033775), {'landcover': '1'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.5207265063588, 27.289168368946708), {'landcover': '2'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.52145606721085, 27.290102771368407), {'landcover': '2'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.5051482364003, 27.283485507382153), {'landcover': '2'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.50218707764786, 27.284972995883066), {'landcover': '2'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.5156839534108, 27.27839356903997), {'landcover': '2'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.48629306130073, 27.30113869755745), {'landcover': '3'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.48846028618476, 27.30337433491876), {'landcover': '3'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.49295566849372, 27.305996027122678), {'landcover': '3'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.49461059145591, 27.306460775187333), {'landcover': '3'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.49771122507713, 27.30860574103437), {'landcover': '3'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.50213150553367, 27.310340749742565), {'landcover': '3'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.48309855036399, 27.29851927411265), {'landcover': '4'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.48760466150901, 27.30126501941927), {'landcover': '4'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.49099497370383, 27.30540257676478), {'landcover': '4'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.50288252405784, 27.310188222592096), {'landcover': '4'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.50105862192771, 27.308033754195737), {'landcover': '5'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.50964169077537, 27.310874593118033), {'landcover': '5'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.5157356696572, 27.312056665737646), {'landcover': '5'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.4934196906533, 27.30488777388401), {'landcover': '5'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.49388962263998, 27.291388052338498), {'landcover': '5'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(91.5377491044515, 27.28543832245818), {'landcover': '5'}) 
]);

//0=Tree Cover 1=Built-up 2=Crop land 3=water bodies 4=Bare land 5=grass land

// Print the FeatureCollection
print('Training Points:', trainingPoints);

// Add a random column to the training points
var trainingPointsWithRandom = trainingPoints.randomColumn('random');
  
// Split into training and testing datasets ( 50% for training, 50% for testing)
var trainingData = trainingPointsWithRandom.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', 0.5));
var testingData = trainingPointsWithRandom.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', 0.5));

// Select bands for feature extraction
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B11', 'B12'];


// Sample pixel values at training and testing locations
var trainingFeatures = Kanglung.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: trainingData,
  properties: ['landcover'],
  scale: 10
});

var testingFeatures = Kanglung.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: testingData,
  properties: ['landcover'],
  scale: 10
});

// Train a Random Forest classifier
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train({
  features: trainingFeatures,
  classProperty: 'landcover',
  inputProperties: bands
});

// Classify the testing features
var classified = testingFeatures.classify(classifier);

// Assess accuracy using a confusion matrix
var accuracy = classified.errorMatrix('landcover', 'classification');

// Print the classification result and accuracy
print('Classification Result', classified);
print('Confusion Matrix', accuracy);
print('Overall Accuracy', accuracy.accuracy());

// Display the classified image
Map.addLayer(classified, {min: 0, max: 4, palette: ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'gray']}, 'Land Cover Classification');
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  As it stands, I think your question would benefit from being heavily revised to describe what you are trying to do and precisely where you are stuck.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Comment: When you say 'my code is not working', it is common courtesy to explain what is not working, and provide an error message if your code produces one. This gives readers a starting point from which to offer help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide your `AOI` so I had to make it using the bounding geometry of your training points. From there, it is quite clear what the problem is, because GEE throws the following error:

> FeatureCollection (Error)
> Property 'landcover' of feature '3_0': Invalid type.
> Expected type: Float.
> Actual type: String.
> Actual value: 0

A cursory look at the documentation of [ee.Classifier.train](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-classifier-train#:%7E:text=to%20train%20on.-,classProperty,feature%20must%20have%20this%20property%2C%20and%20its%20value%20must%20be%20numeric.,-inputProperties) confirms the problem:

| Argument | Type | Details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| classProperty | String | The name of the property containing the class value. Each feature must have this property, and its value must be **numeric**. |

If you look back at how you create your training points, you are passing a string as the value of each `landcover` property.

Remove the quotation marks `'` around the values so that they become integers, rather than strings, and your code will work.

[image]

Comment: I have done the correction but the Land cover Classification is not visible in the map layer. this is my asset (https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-07200451sherubtse/assets/Kanglung). The classification should be 0= tree cover 1= built-up 2= crop land 3= water bodies 4= bare land 5= grass land

Comment: And when I use ee.Classifier.smileCart. // Classify the testing features
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart();
var trainedClassifier = classifier.train({
  features: trainingData,
  classProperty: 'landcover',
  inputProperties: ['bands'] 
});
var classified = testingFeatures.classify(classifier);  . This Error pop up "FeatureCollection (Error)
Classifier.TrainingContainer: Classifier has no training data"

Comment: You are not classifying the image,  you need to add something like `var imgClassified = image.classify(classifier); Map.addLayer(imgClassified, {min: 0, max: 4, palette: ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'gray']}, 'Land Cover Classification');`